# After Deploy on shared hosting , upload file cannot saved at directory . Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, upload

Iam Deploy my project web on shared hosting . and following tutorial to move all on the public(local) folder to public_html(hosting)

my Structure

(/home/sippausr)

laravel

logs

mail

public_ftp

public_html ->

- css
- files
- home
- images
- js
- kalibrasi
- public
- sop
- theme

and now i have a controller to send this data to folder ***files***

My Controller

```
 public function store6(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [


    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('image'))



        {   $file = $request->file('image');
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $name);// i think this problem on here  
            $data = $name;  
        }


    $user = new pemeliharaan;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
    $user->pertanyaan =json_encode($request->except
    (['_token','name','alat_id','status','catatan','image']));
    $user->catatan = $request->catatan;
    $user->image=$data;
    $user->status = $request->status;


    $user->save();
  // dd($user);
    return redirect('user/show6')->with('success', 'Data Telah Terinput');

}
```

but this image cant saved at directory files . this name image is saved on database , but this file is not saved .
how i can fix this ?

Comment: You are most likely running into permission problems. Make sure that the **files** directory has write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have applied a `symlink` and directs you to a different folder?

Try to resolve or make sure that you are pointing to the right path first

If all else fails, you made edit your default saving folder inside the `config / filesystems.php` file

Particularly this portion:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

You may change `root` keys to specifically point to your desired folder.
Since you have mentioned that you have deployed or uploaded it on a hosting, you may try this one, something I have done before and fixed the problem

```
'public' => [
     'driver' => 'local',
     //When I upload my Laravel app in a shared hosting I uncomment the code below, to specifically pinpoint to my "storage" folder of the app
     'root' => '/home/w8p8r839yfqy/public_html/storage/',

     //But when I continue coding locally or in my personal machine, I uncomment the code below
     'root' => storage_path('../public/storage/'),

     'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
     'visibility' => 'public',
 ],
```

Comment: i need change this "root"  like this ->  'root' => '/home/sippausr/public_html/files/',

Comment: not work sir , i change this root like this  'root' => '/home/sippausr/public_html/storage/',